# Angular - Set Default Value For Input Type Number In Form Control

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to set the input type number's default (initial) value as 1 but is having a difficult time figuring out how to do it. I know that I can set the value with `value="1"` if there is no `formControlName`.  I tried `inputNum: new FormControl(1, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[1-9]\\d*$')])`

and

`inputNum: new FormControl([1, Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[1-9]\\d*$')])` without success.

The input should have the initial value of 1 but I should be able to set it as 1 to whatever positive whole number.

```
 <input formControlName="inputNum" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':inputNumForm.touched && inputNumForm.errors}" type="number">
    <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="inputNumForm.touched && inputNumForm.errors">
       <label *ngIf="inputNumForm.errors.required">Numbers Only</label>
    </div>
```

```
  public form = new FormGroup({
    inputNum: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[1-9]\\d*$')]),
  });

  get inputNumForm(): FormControl {
    return this.form.controls['inputNum'] as FormControl;
  }
```

Comment: `this.form.setValue(YOUR_VALUE)` or you can do it directly on the element as there is a `value` property, check: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValue

Comment: @Bargros I totally over complicated the problem and missed this.  Thank you.

Comment: no problem, an upvote then? XD

Comment: I think you forget to add formGroup directive 

Comment: @user9553525 check this demo  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p9lgax

Answer (score 1):

```
 public form = new FormGroup({
    inputNum: new FormControl('1', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[1-9]\\d*$')]),
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the Working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9r3hnw-xnejxn?file=default.html) check out

```
<input text validateDecimalOnType='false' id='numeric' value='1'  />
```